# Google sheets API - Creating sheets properly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

i am developing fitness app and i would like to use simple google sheets to fetch data from.

I would like to make something like:

[image: Google sheets example]

It is possible to structure document somehow and make it work? Or do i need to use something else? Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `structure document somehow and make it work`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thats my bad. Basically i would like to make 3 months training program and every week there will be different training for upperbody and lowerbody. For every session there will be multiple exercises with sets/reps etc. I am asking if its possible to do in sheets, or do i need something else for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use google sheets as a database, you need to duplicate some of those values so that every row contains all the information you need.

For example, in a "Data" tab:

| Week | Training | Area | Exercise | Sets | Reps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Training 1 | Upper body | Rows | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | Training 1 | Lower body | Deadlift | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | Training 2 | Upper body | Bench | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | Training 2 | Lower body | Squat | 4 | 5 |

Then you can fetch the data from other tabs.
For example, say you have a tab with the week number in B1:

1. Select B1, go to Data > data validation
2. List from range: `=Data!$A$2:$A`
3. Press Save and you have a nice drop-down selector for the week numbers
4. in an empty cell put: `=filter(Data!B:F,Data!A:A=B1)`

And this is just an example. You can fetch your information with filters, VLookups, query...